# Are the methods thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

This HardwareData class is simulates the idea of get-and-set and swap instructions in concurrent programming. I used synchronized statement to make sure while doing getAndSet or Swap no other get/set/swap/getandset is happening? Do you guys think this is thread sage?

```
public class HardwareData {

private boolean value = false;

public HardwareData(boolean value){
    this.value = value;
}

public synchronized boolean get(){
    return value;
}

public synchronized void set(boolean newValue){
    value = newValue;
}

public  boolean getAndSet(boolean newValue){
    synchronized(this) {
        boolean oldValue = this.get();
        this.set(newValue);
        return oldValue;
    }


}

public void swap(HardwareData other){
    synchronized(this){
        boolean temp = this.get();
        this.set(other.get());
        other.set(temp);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Do you guys think this is thread safe?`  - No

Comment: If there are two `Thread`s then ThreadA's `this` is not the same Object as  ThreadB's `this` so no point to synchronize on `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not. The `swap` method is not thread safe because you don't hold the mutex of the `other` object during:

```
this.set(other.get());
other.set(temp);
```

meaning that a third thread might be able to call `other.set(boolean)` while you're in between these two lines and therefore change the internal state of `other`. There's also the risk of ending up in a deadlock if two calls to `object1.swap(object2)` and `object2.swap(object1)` happen at the same time.

To solve this problem, the `swap` method must be synchronizing on the two objects at the same time, which is tricky because it can lead to deadlocks depending on the order they're acquired.

Also: adding `synchronize` to the method declaration is the same as wrapping the entire method body in `synchronized(this){ ... }`.

Comment: How do I make sure that the changes within this and other object happend atomically?

Comment: One way to do it is create a global mutex like `static final Object mutex = new Object()` and then synchronize the bodies of all methods using that global `mutex` object.